# How to measure bandwidth of a WebRTC data channel

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is there a best way to measure incoming or outgoing message size of a WebRTC message?

Comment: I am assuming you want this to be browser independent(FF, Chrome and Opera)?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up altering PeerJS to return a Blob on `connection.send`.  This blob has a size parameter, in bytes.  I don't know (yet) if this is exactly the size-on wire, but it seems like a good start.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.size

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options

1. You have chrome://webrtc-internals there you can see the incoming and outgoing throughput of your data channel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6oIQ.jpg
2. By message size you mean just your application's payload? or including SCTP, IP, etc' overheads?

Comment: The data channel is listed in chrome://webrtc-internals, but I could not find anything about the consumed bandwidth. For video and audio it is shown. It is a bit difficult to read, so maybe I missed it.

Comment: @CapK I've updated the answer with a link to an image showing it.